# NixOps deployment on x86_64-darwin (vs. x86_64-linux)

Tags: mac-osx, nix

We are having problems using NixOps from Mac OS X due to the different arch:

```
x86_64-darwin (vs.) x86_64-linux
```

We have a built-host setup according to this manual(s):

- Nix installation 
   https://nixos.org/nix/download.html
- build-host setup (VirtualBox guest) 
  https://functional-orbitz.blogspot.de/2013/05/setting-up-nixops-on-mac-os-x-with.html

  (see step 5. Setup Distributed Builds)

  ```
  ssh nix-build-server
  ```

  works and we set these environment variables on the mac:

  ```
  NIX_BUILD_HOOK
  NIX_CURRENT_LOAD
  NIX_REMOTE_SYSTEMS
  ```

  with the values from the manual.

**Question.** On Linux i would use: `strace -f -e execve nixops ...` to see what programs are called or at least to see what arguments they are called with. How to find out what command returned the **unexpected end-of-file** error?

**Error.** We see that nixops wants to use the buildhost and outputs:

```
nixops deploy -d test -I nixpkgs=/Users/josh/.nix-defexpr/channels/nixos/ --show-trace
building all machine configurations...
using predefined remote systems file: /Users/josh/sample_clj/remote-systems.conf
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/85hnzp3jmrm34jd3lzjf5d7i8sqlvbd4-pam-environment.drv
  /nix/store/013p0nb0iynrz0sb1y9l6w25n8ydmjph-sudo.pam.drv
  /nix/store/03wzv8y1yv51nj119lgimfm44lffnvxl-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/0712xdzwdf63cv63lycdx6sqd6j6x703-issue.drv
  /nix/store/9d0jrm4158i0dh157xdyjpjqlwb8z68r-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/0753r878n6j5cw05bx8j7vvd2pqdzbax-unit-nixos-upgrade.service.drv
  /nix/store/0k232qxqgg5il6aigmyhw1s7wywlphfb-etc-subuid.drv
  /nix/store/0ps2s31si6c4rhfavnyr3x1k7dlfj4h4-sshd.pam.drv
  /nix/store/0ylsqnm11xk9hpq9jj3jbi34cw45v01g-etc-nsswitch.conf.drv
  /nix/store/1847n1wj39dzg4varrrrq8j8anq5q4vr-vconsole.conf.drv
  /nix/store/1qfl4qnlpqlr169hnfbfpwcgmq5y94vb-useradd.drv
  /nix/store/mfwd1cicw1lxmbqwn5din4zir9df0vsy-mdadm.conf.drv
  /nix/store/2a12n4csg37pbdasali7rvn0sqy5qi54-kernel-modules-shrunk.drv
  /nix/store/97c4jxy53qfqvw8k2v99nbkwdknz879v-initrd-fsinfo.drv
  /nix/store/mzxzgmrvxmf4cgffp9w7x49syzflknzw-stage-1-init.sh.drv
  /nix/store/1zsacaxbm80kn66cjc9nw5zpjkj5qw11-initrd.drv
  /nix/store/202fwmvli84z2r3zaks5shmc19xx6wp1-unit-network-interfaces.target.drv
  /nix/store/2c95r4imi9d2lxk675n4cb49g5qxy6jl-chsh.pam.drv
  /nix/store/2hxa9b8y73rplk1phyy71rkmqd13swyb-groupmod.pam.drv
  /nix/store/2i9lsv9y4nqs0yv0wyv6aa6dlg2c1d2w-unit-nixops-keys.service-disabled.drv
  /nix/store/2mk45g38gs8lwxdpvyx05r587z25f12h-i3lock.pam.drv
  /nix/store/34za8ycrgnymc4y98zyxlhv9d0jafalk-groupadd.pam.drv
  /nix/store/3df52px99lir5ssn30vh7c8a1nqydabz-unit-local-fs.target.drv
  /nix/store/cy3gcqvw40vbms7hs7lpdi4ywwnnffm8-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/3f214dbvsqvcpdscgy3gbm25dywjxqn1-unit-nix-gc.service.drv
  /nix/store/3gfqbnfc0i87qy9kz2yw5x0vg2rb1w3g-su.pam.drv
  /nix/store/3kr5ckbxbm4ix7zx2fjazlzn72q22731-nixos.conf.drv
  /nix/store/3m43c4gpndgf1p19vah6090fg9q5lngn-groupdel.pam.drv
  /nix/store/4z4pmxva6ashgv4sr8gc1r2bv1pj0ypa-etc-logind.conf.drv
  /nix/store/3y21wvpq0x0wsaq43vrqpa5zmlpxg694-unit-systemd-logind.service.drv
  /nix/store/3yckn30pxrxmb6g84rgv8c1ll0mia1db-etc-nixos.conf.drv
  /nix/store/gv8rjhs71npjd6z4rfb7jm3v22zkizc0-dbus-catalog.xml.drv
  /nix/store/77cgrfksm4vcgv5fcxwcs71kbv9ppbzf-nixos-help.drv
  /nix/store/rpkh8y2fgnhxrc9550w98yx95fiwx6b2-system-path.drv
  /nix/store/3zl87lpm90771dwffdqrq7cvgqgll4v3-dbus-1.drv
  /nix/store/43i1wc857f7yvk1wya963fmhgr34ab5f-unit-systemd-modules-load.service.drv
  /nix/store/47j8wxgbb12j3jc1mlvxj336aclj5cld-cups.pam.drv
  /nix/store/nbahasdvgagky1bhhzhdjavgn455vr90-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/4933il5r6hvil21vlh300294rvy58jfy-unit-network-local-commands.service.drv
  /nix/store/crnbwmh8vfrjyjahkds0xzanp55wp7ip-container-init.drv
  /nix/store/4ir2hk0adfn5zxmjlpb2s5nz5nzm6rvs-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/822rhr0xrfq0ifqkkvzamiizgm5cpk35-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/4nnxiizd8vljkcjyxc8wlcip1jfbzysy-unit-network-setup.service.drv
  /nix/store/4qnc2sh1gdw623p1xjav1rpysi09p9dn-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/5mi8j6m0aj1ipdz2x4xxjp5zpvd2krk4-login.pam.drv
  /nix/store/5qgfzc91c8i4l5jhm361mb3h891zlrl8-userdel.pam.drv
  /nix/store/aicdqpqvhbwjfy5w3g9yxjljckmvpl8w-etc-hosts.drv
  /nix/store/j8vya3iy4dz7vkakczzgzjvw1qvjz9q9-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/nlf2j2cl48hdrlv3jvm407xxx5830r2a-etc-nscd.conf.drv
  /nix/store/626sns8f8y897n67iby6b8p7swb8zyv0-unit-nscd.service.drv
  /nix/store/6iafaag8xnmmrc2xnz4hz7svff2m10bc-unit-acme-selfsigned-certificates.target.drv
  /nix/store/6lw6hi40sf3fzw0yvnd3kdq023ans1ia-etc-host.conf.drv
  /nix/store/7a0jqfk91akdgdbyd9qxdwfhf3prd8lj-etc-subgid.drv
  /nix/store/i5y57jcyngmakjx3axj9y26y5hldd18l-etc-journald.conf.drv
  /nix/store/7c5ad56ccy29bshqd0hnqjc5p3c28d50-unit-systemd-journald.service.drv
  /nix/store/82nc3xa0sbf36g0xkj97dxmhp333vh96-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/nmm2bayl0889krn87zzhalj5gzk5z3q3-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/qbgw7c8d45a1m0f0knyh9bc83axia5yh-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/8ilviqpqjxk70nsh5nldawnvghwxkb2r-unit-acme-selfsigned-uberjar.nixcloud.it.service.drv
  /nix/store/8nm5vfyspnc8k281afypjc0fiixya75b-etc-user.conf.drv
  /nix/store/8slqlyyy0lvhm01qkjisf0ywwyq2myk3-etc-timesyncd.conf.drv
  /nix/store/8smx6mfykzs7far95qlqys0knczdqci5-unit-systemd-timesyncd.service.drv
  /nix/store/9bjcwbz4p9xwbykxr0c2bjb8kfidpm7j-polkit-1.pam.drv
  /nix/store/9fhdfylm8pc97wmxb6dw1ll4hx9w7lsj-unit-systemd-journal-flush.service.drv
  /nix/store/9mjc8vvyfjy4bhbi6kzzjblpz98yi78g-unit-systemd-fsck-.service.drv
  /nix/store/a8c6ygcc9v3803cyykvhcgv4gb4w7kil-unit-nix-daemon.service.drv
  /nix/store/a8kc7kffysc5nn8sv0gpbmgx1qh73pm0-chfn.pam.drv
  /nix/store/adad9izsdy86bbwha63p399z55ziirh8-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/adkd93pxa3vsn9sih4ll8fkm77chv0v4-unit-console-getty.service-disabled.drv
  /nix/store/ay87p8yzq7gbkbcy8n2qnbyk52j8bsfy-grub-config.xml.drv
  /nix/store/b2vxkd8rccpjnaccbzsqwa7alg7nzw58-unit-dbus.socket.drv
  /nix/store/iy737gcqimhcbd3lqdqfr1c1sc6ik6jd-extra-hwdb-file.drv
  /nix/store/s0as5mqpqignfx7nblw296c54cwg7p9m-extra-udev-rules.drv
  /nix/store/bhwn2qlzg5akx4vkrspfapk39nznr0yb-udev-rules.drv
  /nix/store/d1fj1f31g1ad5vv6ya3zwmxxagmcgjw0-runuser.pam.drv
  /nix/store/dfk4w0rxb8qsszf1vs7i7khapj94g7cr-etc-system.conf.drv
  /nix/store/dvys5b1c9q6vzrshhh64ngj5z5741a8v-other.pam.drv
  /nix/store/f5j0dllyv54z207riwgscw2nm233qm5s-client.conf.drv
  /nix/store/frddp8arycx9mmrvjbd646ybwf3l1jd7-ftp.pam.drv
  /nix/store/gnh35blfq2asnk2d0g7lsi04z5yxbkjj-etc-os-release.drv
  /nix/store/h5mz9v1vj34mlxxnlldh8750fvccmpqi-etc-bashrc.drv
  /nix/store/hfcgf9p3v8g46n5d1vcka2aq1q582wdd-dhcpcd.exit-hook.drv
  /nix/store/hg0iybbbqp9wx1x3hpc8pgbm59rdi9bx-runuser-l.pam.drv
  /nix/store/hwch6qsjwrazdhxh70fabsy2xqlc4zbb-etc-sleep.conf.drv
  /nix/store/k0vby2vrgl4wy8m0ab211d0h8yak3mar-passwd.pam.drv
  /nix/store/ky6dwrqlxq0gbp7p4818vllnlg5xqvjf-usermod.pam.drv
  /nix/store/lz7d9l6rjpbd7csl9yx5hgyhah9izhwa-etc-nixos.conf.drv
  /nix/store/m6dckfj4fk182v0870a00hzw5i66i9pw-login.defs.drv
  /nix/store/mxlg8wgmjwm3nks2hzzaknb1ng8kzc8s-i3lock-color.pam.drv
  /nix/store/n5hb29ylzv9gd4fph4n1q0gqyiqn3ry6-chpasswd.pam.drv
  /nix/store/phmncd0dvasgf5sky519hdvx03i42gyg-vlock.pam.drv
  /nix/store/pjdavkgpk8487pbw7l1sd611lm5bdycf-screen.pam.drv
  /nix/store/pjz04gsmdpmwl3zdaj1z9v7zrb56yxa8-useradd.pam.drv
  /nix/store/r2w7fxajkmcjxsmygbfcnc4j3iscxkqg-set-environment.drv
  /nix/store/pz8bjvvww3vjigs0647ryi2fblsaab41-etc-profile.drv
  /nix/store/qa8641mf4wz3nlv2lnmpwaq42fc23hdk-groupmems.pam.drv
  /nix/store/qywrr89kv00ksk8drkfyb4vhck67b4cg-etc-shells.drv
  /nix/store/rccccbrbdz0dzaxyvpl79ciqia8x3bz9-etc-resolvconf.conf.drv
  /nix/store/rihqdbf8ylbqrsm4mrh0x0351jpq2kbi-locale.conf.drv
  /nix/store/rjpwi6b6572jddjzv6b7ddwc4bg6nqia-etc-fstab.drv
  /nix/store/rl7j4r6jn4v0byvgba0kmlx46zfyd7pc-etc-nixos.conf.drv
  /nix/store/rv8696qldwk7j5gcxigd25nq4yy874nw-xlock.pam.drv
  /nix/store/sai8jca953s3r9ji1r55xvaiy4mivwbr-root-authorized_keys.drv
  /nix/store/sgdhnyvnlf10nkv6lc8v6mx8mgr3ng4d-hwdb.bin.drv
  /nix/store/wcxf1m8s9lswhnkg85ym95da8mirspk5-etc-10-nixos.rules.drv
  /nix/store/wqb1fw1aqw1lj49317a2sc66if22psmy-etc-hostname.drv
  /nix/store/y537jpx8gkjxkkaywsh4cr7m331p3nfj-smb-dummy.conf.drv
  /nix/store/y8b2ab82qnj6m09micnhzmpx4sx8ipkv-etc-ssh_config.drv
  /nix/store/yc93g3ap02n0z04rcay2w6mcc15pz6cy-etc-ssh_known_hosts.drv
  /nix/store/crkhsck51zra793ncjr2vi0wpaif3m88-unit-pre-sleep.service.drv
  /nix/store/d9gdvbi7wp7vfb845999lnk85pr1x3ym-unit-encrypted-links.target.drv
  /nix/store/dsb2rfv49qrnzbqwrm2zqxs3n2nzqb8g-unit-save-hwclock.service.drv
  /nix/store/jwwrjnzni80547pa4i16kdsahr9rzph2-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/zfq4ryh1c1zm0cqlszbg0pryhd2czdfc-nginx.conf.drv
  /nix/store/dwba30hgif2y4c4x2qd9nzmx03mksk16-unit-nginx.service.drv
  /nix/store/f2dfb82a9qn09jqw76mqiwmw7sn6jspp-unit-alsa-store.service.drv
  /nix/store/f44g7l4839na004d0yi947006qjnixic-unit-fs.target.drv
  /nix/store/fsqm324bv2246yl9qp36wkdbdajmjf4a-unit-systemd-random-seed.service.drv
  /nix/store/fx1jpwx9ixp3jkl9cyd0is0apr8i6hk6-unit-systemd-update-utmp.service.drv
  /nix/store/g3k6bsbsjf2gjj57qnlrf43cc3hx5pwp-unit-polkit.service.drv
  /nix/store/iijg4kpa9i5wa8ywffl30mpjldlp34n4-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/g60g6kyrnjz3yna0gqlnq59map1zi67l-unit-post-resume.service.drv
  /nix/store/hq53j48l54rf66ff5vfxnvn3fwk9pg7q-dhcpcd.conf.drv
  /nix/store/gbszc2a075vxfhypbaxylrjjbq1pi1q4-unit-dhcpcd.service.drv
  /nix/store/gxn12wz0zg01f4vrkg6p9ap49lrl0sk4-unit-dbus.service.drv
  /nix/store/kfldq0r9cfkw5h9vxngf2c255six1b0d-firewall-stop.drv
  /nix/store/wy61vycij522w5wpa2ab510m0h4fy54j-firewall-start.drv
  /nix/store/x8nb9s63s0hbyrg2kb6ndqbjhlspqsp4-firewall-reload.drv
  /nix/store/h8hrx6ibkfmab6zlbxkmnvz2lpdz4c6d-unit-firewall.service.drv
  /nix/store/i26xpix8wcz3hgn0zmj43gj7b4sds6wi-unit-systemd-backlight-.service.drv
  /nix/store/gq5apjw6d8x2kd0y5kk18igcj0lsxc9i-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/hgj26986g3qm8mxvb6dw6hmfbsyfwfga-reload-container.drv
  /nix/store/v7lf6qmwxxp7gpf7b86gqxmxiizcyk6c-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/x6l3grvvar6812p63n20r3vhw9qynh5b-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/i95ap7psd4sfh99y4g07pi0kw2yw21ry-unit-container-.service.drv
  /nix/store/ibbs60slmzvasnwlwlcbzjwd5wi57zgl-unit-systemd-binfmt.service.drv
  /nix/store/iimz1i0wd4v6nbxj1h1r6zsfxwxwr7gz-unit-nix-daemon.socket.drv
  /nix/store/kw3qn8fph3y5g20wys7r9qbfw9c0dpvb-audit-disable.drv
  /nix/store/w91gks3hvjqbnscq53yhzc7qy01d56r5-audit-stop.drv
  /nix/store/j0b85r1djmp09wqklmcs0mlx9z5liqf6-unit-audit.service.drv
  /nix/store/jwi6cw75n0nxql44b75jvg53xff3fb0r-unit-post-resume.target.drv
  /nix/store/jxf385r8x2h5l6ihn7ci4c3wk9bwshsj-unit-systemd-sysctl.service.drv
  /nix/store/izihsk2qll7lzhsygqiym3xfmm4g3igy-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/qcc5f55741kp9x7dbvnlsn5h5phj2i79-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/k59nf5h79nypg0jyg8bxlmw3sqvb3q7q-unit-acme-uberjar.nixcloud.it.service.drv
  /nix/store/fz4hpv264a0y4l35cv759hdl2gspdwim-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/wq29gscr7r600k2xm34ria09hjszy00p-sshd_config.drv
  /nix/store/ka5vinvz7af74s7b2lg86vsk98m9idw0-unit-sshd.service.drv
  /nix/store/kh4j981jgik1lkqd9xrfx7ckynqrkmbp-unit-remote-fs.target.drv
  /nix/store/cwi7ql27v6qwhy20aswmax3ja8bsrzfg-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/kscsdx5sk70yyj8d02blc01df9mqyzpg-unit-rethinkdb.service.drv
  /nix/store/l056y906a738ypmjj79n4im65z1sh6sx-unit-systemd-user-sessions.service.drv
  /nix/store/l2l9dv11gkn4xk1xjavxh6ryram0xyvd-unit-user-.service.drv
  /nix/store/l3zc3r8b6ilma821icypg0ljidlghc9f-unit-systemd-vconsole-setup.service.drv
  /nix/store/lha3mj9i2map4gcaih6qyy2l1mf6lb8y-unit-mdadm-shutdown.service.drv
  /nix/store/lmrvhzc4wzqxx92bb7gi1yz0752gqkaj-unit-acme-uberjar.nixcloud.it.timer.drv
  /nix/store/j4mdzsawfyw55p16cpl2f88szkkjmd1y-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/ls611jjszj799sq328pc0k5hfg78q9jy-unit-prepare-kexec.service.drv
  /nix/store/mzbb4z4ldpgz7khq0zmy6bgp4yhgldg1-unit-udisks2.service.drv
  /nix/store/np5xmsj6dy6kh5bwfd8l9dn79kwiim8l-unit-nix-optimise.service.drv
  /nix/store/p4ijhjwg5402gxp81a09ggskvp7fhjqh-unit-mdmon-.service.drv
  /nix/store/q17lcfry9vf20njakynw2rkpn9adjsn5-unit-acme-certificates.target.drv
  /nix/store/rs34ljbmrrihkclypnp8fi08nmmf1q90-unit-container-getty-.service.drv
  /nix/store/sh5937bdvanx4ib9gnraj1h834g1c61x-unit-systemd-udevd.service.drv
  /nix/store/sw8q7jq7hnkb99xsvvlbqf3i6ln5clsp-unit-systemd-remount-fs.service.drv
  /nix/store/v95ppj13xn6gw21qm79rr447m4ym32s1-unit-mdadm-grow-continue-.service.drv
  /nix/store/vqr98pdib3bid45vypd8dx4yij03yc1n-unit-systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket.drv
  /nix/store/wgc2lzfasrsqz9vlcd409nrfz3i1mmyc-unit-getty-.service.drv
  /nix/store/jwvn4djf03mg6v6y19shs6qjxadpql6f-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/y2jhrf1zwi1cx2sa73fyfz8a3avqjhf5-unit-script.drv
  /nix/store/wgmc8j5b8q3lzm04lnzwhpyw0pml3q1p-unit-network-addresses-enp0s3.service.drv
  /nix/store/wnaw22mzf1arr4hg7dk0dk3z5nl2ndz3-unit-cpufreq.service.drv
  /nix/store/x8hcf1ywaibyrkgyzhwclf640kfdi9b0-unit-network-online.target.drv
  /nix/store/yyslyh88bysmrk9pywpbbmnd2q3sjq1k-unit-serial-getty-.service.drv
  /nix/store/z7f7ab23shl6s9h1q3shr9avgdslargg-unit-keys.target.drv
  /nix/store/zy3l5k9i97i85c05if0xvqhwkp5i3y69-unit-network-link-enp0s3.service.drv
  /nix/store/zcc7j2lcjhs6px5ibj78xgbzlny8zx32-system-units.drv
  /nix/store/zpwszimkmrgdwimpgsa3m5j37si9ynji-xscreensaver.pam.drv
  /nix/store/qbpyf9bzd6j6g1nq41fijzlanwmvnw10-unit-ssh-agent.service.drv
  /nix/store/zqxi8mrficic5hlcsr0wga1g89ciq42l-user-units.drv
  /nix/store/zrkwjh24x5g782c1p03hi76p37g48f4x-systemd-user.pam.drv
  /nix/store/bia7ch5mfyrvbnfazbxs4464r1dfvix6-etc.drv
  /nix/store/f595klx7286cs3b37dyjjxj970c25pqb-users-groups.json.drv
  /nix/store/jz5d9lwg7sjb951p89gzqxdhvyc1ya4a-append-initrd-secrets.drv
  /nix/store/lc7frsag1qmdakxqipg760zdzli4lf5l-install-grub.sh.drv
  /nix/store/xh7j0za7sfmjyf8bnvh87k36iyqijg0l-nixos-system-uberjarServer-17.03.1395.9b948ea439.drv
  /nix/store/x270f41slfi7zy869qzdx1v1fm1y4vl8-nixops-machines.drv
waiting for locks or build slots...
copying 73 missing paths (0.19 MiB) to ‘root@nix-build-server’...
error: unexpected end-of-file
copying 57 missing paths (0.14 MiB) to ‘root@nix-build-server’...
error: unexpected end-of-file
copying 57 missing paths (0.13 MiB) to ‘root@nix-build-server’...
error: unexpected end-of-file
copying 57 missing paths (0.13 MiB) to ‘root@nix-build-server’...
error: unexpected end-of-file
copying 278 missing paths (0.63 MiB) to ‘root@nix-build-server’...
cannot build derivation ‘/nix/store/xh7j0za7sfmjyf8bnvh87k36iyqijg0l-nixos-system-uberjarServer-17.03.1395.9b948ea439.drv’: 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation ‘/nix/store/x270f41slfi7zy869qzdx1v1fm1y4vl8-nixops-machines.drv’: 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of ‘/nix/store/x270f41slfi7zy869qzdx1v1fm1y4vl8-nixops-machines.drv’ failed
error: unable to build all machine configurations
```

Answer (score 1):

## solution

for the time being do not use nixops from your mac machine directly! this seems tempting but we tried get it working it for hours to no avail! using https://functional-orbitz.blogspot.de/2013/05/setting-up-nixops-on-mac-os-x-with.html did not work for us at all. in fact, that was a huge waste of time.

**instead: install nixos into VirtualBox and do the nixops deployment from there!**

## future solution

the most promising project in this regard seems to be nixos in hyperkit:

https://github.com/puffnfresh/nixpkgs/blob/feature/hyperkit-builder/pkgs/build-support/vm/hyperkit/default.nix

but they are not there yet. they would then build x86_64-linux code from a x86_64-darwin machine transparently.

so once the hyperkit-builder is more stable i'd switch to that toolchain instead of using VirtualBox with nixos guest.

Comment: Running NixOps from MacOS — and using a Linux machine as a build slave — is [pretty straightforward](https://medium.com/@zw3rk/provisioning-a-nixos-server-from-macos-d36055afc4ad).